# Group by binary operator in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, aggregates

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2.4.

### Question

I have a table with an ID and a second column of some type. Let's call the type `X`. I also have a binary function that operates on a pair of `X`s and returns a boolean. We'll call this function `f`. `f` is transitive; i.e., if `f(a,b)` and `f(b,c)` both return true, then `f(a,c)` will as well.

What I want to do is a get a set of IDs for which all pairs the second column give back true for this binary function. How can I accomplish this?

Performance is not a huge concern; this is part of an import process that will only be run about once annually. The database will not be in use otherwise during this import.

### (Relatively) Simple Example

I've created a SQL Fiddle to get things started: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/57b97/3. I want to collect IDs by the result of the `f` function. Keep in mind that in general, `f` might be more complicated. This is just an example.

The output I'm looking for with this example SQL Fiddle would be something like the following:

```
{1,3,6}
{2,4}
```

For example, say we choose any pair of IDs from a single set. Let's say we pick `1` and `3`. Then `SELECT f((SELECT data FROM temp WHERE id = 1), (SELECT data FROM temp WHERE id = 3));` returns true.

`5` doesn't show up anywhere because `'green'` is the only string of length 5. It would be fine if I got back duplicates; I can figure out how to clean them up.

### Real Situation Details

In reality, my "second column" is a PostGIS `GEOMETRY(LINESTRING)` and my "binary function" is `ST_Equals`. So really, I'm searching for a bunch of duplicate line strings. I don't feel like this information is relevant to the question at hand other than showing I can't simplify the problem down to easier to handle operations.

Comment: I would appreciate any help on how I can clarify this without adding gobs of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with Clodoaldo Neto's answer a while, I finally got it.

```
WITH matches AS (
    select t1.id id1, t2.id id2
    from temp t1
    inner join temp t2 on t1.id < t2.id
    where f(t1.data, t2.data)
)
SELECT id1 || ARRAY_AGG(id2)
FROM matches
WHERE id1 NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id2 FROM matches)
GROUP BY id1
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/57b97/14

The CTE comes straight from Clodoaldo Neto's inner query. This is really nice because it also lets me split them and have the lowest ID by itself if I want:

```
WITH matches AS (select t1.id id1, t2.id id2
                 from temp t1
                 inner join temp t2 on t1.id < t2.id
                 where f(t1.data, t2.data)
                )
SELECT id1, ARRAY_AGG(id2) AS duplicates
FROM matches
WHERE id1 NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id2 FROM matches)
GROUP BY id1
```

Answer (score 1):

Start fiddling with this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/57b97/5)

```
select
    t1.id id1,
    t1.data data1,
    t2.id id2,
    t2.data data2,
    f(t1.data, t2.data) f
from
    temp t1
    inner join
    temp t2 on t1.id < t2.id
order by t1.id, t2.id
```

And then go to the final version [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/57b97/7)

```
select array[id1] || array_agg(id2) id2
from (
    select t1.id id1, t2.id id2
    from
        temp t1
        inner join
        temp t2 on t1.id < t2.id
    where f(t1.data, t2.data)
) s
group by id1
order by id1, id2
```

Comment: First, thanks! Second, I'm sorry. I should've been more clear in my question. I meant duplicates within an array. Any thoughts on eliminating the 3rd row (which contains a subset of the first row)?